# One class will not import into anther class how to fix this problem?

Tags: java, constants

I made a class that holds constants as shown all classes are in the default src folder

```
public final class SectionType {
    public static final String LABS = "LABS";
    public static final String LAB_REPORTS = "LABREPORTS";
    public static final String HOMEWORK = "HOMEWORK";
    public static final String EXAM01 = "EXAM 1";
    public static final String EXAM02 = "EXAM 2";
    public static final String FINAL = "FINAL";
}
```

I now need to use these constants in another class like this

```
import static SectionType.*;
public class Student {
public void addGrade(SectionType type, double grade) {
            if(type.equals(EXAM01)) {
                this.exam01 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(EXAM02)) {
                this.exam02 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(FINAL)) {
                this.finalExam = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(LABS)) {
                this.labSum += grade;
                this.labCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(LAB_REPORTS)) {
                this.labRSum += grade;
                this.labRCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(HOMEWORK)) {
                this.hwSum += grade;
                this.hwCount++;
            }
        }
}
```

what is the best way to get this to work?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: You just do: `import your.package.SectionType.LAB_REPORTS`, for instance ;)

Comment: Yes, that's how you import constants to use in another class like this. But out of curiosity, have you considered using an enum for SectionType?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Are you getting an error? Which one?)

Comment: @x80486 this is in the default package do I need to change anything

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thew homework wants this to be done with classes

Comment: SectionType isn't an object, but you're trying to use it like it is. If you use enum instead, like @Roddy recommended, then you can use it the way you want.

Comment: @meriton the error given is The import SectionType cannot be resolved

Comment: @NathanHughes how do I change the first class to enums?

Answer (score 0):

SectionType isn't an object, but you're trying to use it like it is. All it is is a class with static members, there isn't a concept of different instances of a class, each taking on their own value.

To make the existing code work you could change the code to pass in a String for section type, like this:

```
import static SectionType.*;

public class Student {

public void addGrade(String type, double grade) {
            if(type.equals(EXAM01)) {
                this.exam01 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(EXAM02)) {
                this.exam02 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(FINAL)) {
                this.finalExam = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(LABS)) {
                this.labSum += grade;
                this.labCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(LAB_REPORTS)) {
                this.labRSum += grade;
                this.labRCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(HOMEWORK)) {
                this.hwSum += grade;
                this.hwCount++;
            }
        }
}
```

But it would be better to make SectionType an enum:

```
public enum SectionType {
    LABS, LAB_REPORTS, HOMEWORK, EXAM01, EXAM02, FINAL
}
```

where this specifically says there is a concept of SectionType where there is one instance of it for each value (LABS is one SectionType, LAB_REPORTS is a different SectionType, etc.), which is how your code expects to use it.

(The advantage of using the enum is that you can take advantage of compile-time type-checking. If an invalid string value is passed in, the code just falls through without doing anything. But that can't happen with code using enums, you have to convert the input value to a valid enum before you can call the code. When a string value is entered, it is converted to an enum using SectionType.valueOf, which will throw an exception if the value is invalid.)

It sounds like what you are being asked to do is to implement the obsolete [typesafe enumeration pattern](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwidrOuCj7rkAhUEOKwKHcW7B24QFjAAegQIAhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.javapractices.com%2Ftopic%2FTopicAction.do%3FId%3D1&usg=AOvVaw28wwq2mX8n6U-SdY4zN4HI), like:

```
public abstract class SectionType {
    // left as an exercise            
}

class Lab extends SectionType {
    public Lab() {
        super("Lab");
    }

class LabReports extends SectionType {
    public LabReports() {
        super("LabReports");   
    }
}
```

which is very similar to enum, just more verbose, and more error-prone. Problems with this pattern were the motivation for creating enums. See [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwidrOuCj7rkAhUEOKwKHcW7B24QFjABegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.javaworld.com%2Farticle%2F2077487%2Fjava-tip-122--beware-of-java-typesafe-enumerations.html&usg=AOvVaw3vAk0sfxxnXLHvjlTX9jh8) for a list of reasons that implementing type safe enumerations is not a good idea.

Comment: @Exodition: sure. btw i added the approach it sounds like your course wants, along with warnings about the issues if you do this in real-life.

Answer (score 0):

the addGrade class was changed to the following

```
public void addGrade(String type, double grade) {
            if(type.equals(SectionType.EXAM01)) {
                this.exam01 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(SectionType.EXAM02)) {
                this.exam02 = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(SectionType.FINAL)) {
                this.finalExam = grade;
            }
            if(type.equals(SectionType.LABS)) {
                this.labSum += grade;
                this.labCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(SectionType.LAB_REPORTS)) {
                this.labRSum += grade;
                this.labRCount++;
            }
            if(type.equals(SectionType.HOMEWORK)) {
                this.hwSum += grade;
                this.hwCount++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

if import is what you are looking for then simply import the class like any other package you import

```
import path.where.the.package.is.className;
```

though it would be good to copy the class to the project you are working on and then import it.

also some suggestion are:

1. using `static` for the class i.e `public static final class SectionType` so you don't need to create an instance of this class when you use it.
2. another option can be to use enum

Comment: the classes are in the root folder I tried ./ and root and both did not work

Comment: can you specify the path where the class is??